# Python Optimize multiple if-else based on truthy value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code in Python where based on a boolean flag I need to check a list count, wondering if there is a better way to code this in Python?

```
If var_true:
    if len(something) > 0:
        logger.console (“Something found”)
    else:
        raise AssertionError(“something was not found”)
If not var_true:
    if len(something) == 0:
        logger.console (“Something not expected to be found, was not seen”)
    else:
        raise AssertionError(“something unexpected was found”)
```

Comment: Id recommened heading over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as this is working code and usually SO works with `non-working or buggy code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `else: raise AssertionError` code with the actual `assert` statement (which lets it get skipped when run in `-O` mode, but behaves identically to your current code in normal [debug] mode):

```
if var_true:
    assert something, "something was not found"  # Also remove len checks; sequences are naturally truthy when non-empty
    logger.console("Something found")
else:
    assert not something, "something unexpected was found"  # Same length check removal
    logger.console("Something not expected to be found, was not seen")
```

During testing (or all the time, your choice if you never run with `-O`) you'll be told if your assumption is violated. In release mode, you'll skip the tests that should never be hit and run a little faster.

If this is *not* a case where the `assert` case should *never* occur unless a developer made a mistake, you shouldn't use `assert` or `AssertionError` (both of which imply an "impossible" thing has occurred), and should instead raise some other appropriate exception, e.g. `ValueError` for when an invalid value was supplied.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, this looks really sleek. Cheers.